# Check if a Windows ListBox contains a string c# ignorecase?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (!lstFieldData.Items.Contains(ItemValue))
        MessageBox.Show(ItemValue + "Item not found.");
```

Above code is to get the list of items that is not in the list.
Now i want to check this with ignoring the case. How do i?

Comment: no.. that's list. My question is specific for ListBox.

Comment: @DDave - The answer is the same. Otherwise, what have you tried/researched?

Comment: @Sayse not really. It requires Enumerable object. Isn't it. I tried that too.

Comment: [`ListBox.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is IEnumerable

Comment: This worked for me...thanx all

if (!lstFieldData.Items.Cast<String>().ToList().Contains(ItemValue,StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

Comment: You have to cast, a ListBox contains objects, not strings.  Use lstFieldData.Items.Cast<string>().Contains(ItemValue, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lstFieldData consists of only capital letters or lower letters you can use .ToUpper() or .ToLower().

```
lstFieldData
    A
    B
    C
    D

    if (!lstFieldData.Items.Contains(ItemValue.ToUpper()))
            MessageBox.Show(ItemValue + "Item not found.");
lstFieldData
a
b
c
d
    if (!lstFieldData.Items.Contains(ItemValue.ToLower()))
            MessageBox.Show(ItemValue + "Item not found.");
```

Comment: Provide code that you are talking about?

Comment: but my listbox is not sured about capitals ONLY or Lower latter only. It can be any...

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strCompare.Equals("testcompare", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
///
}
```

try this